For what $(a,b)$ does a pattern exist such that it can be formed with $a$ or $b$ non-overlapping equilateral triangles?
My question is slightly too long to fit into the title, here's the full thing:

For what positive integers $a$ and $b$ where $a \le b$ does a geometric pattern exist that can be formed with $a$ non-overlapping equilateral triangles, or separately $b$ non-overlapping equilateral triangles? (Crossing does not count as overlapping.)


In addition, two restrictions:

No triangle cannot be in the same position, orientation, and size in both constructions.
The constructions cannot be able to be non-trivially broken up into smaller parts with different $a$-$b$ values that sum to the final $a$-$b$ value in the same way (see Empy2's comment).


This question is somewhat long-winded and confusing; an example will hopefully make things very clear. Take the following pattern (first iteration of the Sierpinski triangle):

You can construct this pattern with three equally sized equilateral triangles, one on each corner. But it can also be constructed with two non-equally sized equilateral triangles, one making up the entire outside of the pattern and one upside down in the middle. Visually:

Therefore, the pair $a = 2$ and $b = 3$ satisfies my question.
Another example (the shape is the Star of David):

This shape can be formed with two equally sized equilateral triangles, one of which is upside down and directly on top of the other (remember, crossing is allowed, just not overlapping), or with six equally sized equilateral triangles, one for each point of the star. So the pair $a = 2$ and $b = 6$ satisfies my question as well.
Our final example, a variation of the Sierpinski triangle:

It can be formed with $3$ triangles (the one on the outside, the one inside that, and the one inside that). It can also be formed with $4$ triangles (the big triangle on the outside and the three small triangles inside it). In addition, there is another way for it to be formed with $4$ triangles (the three triangles on the outside and the tiny triangle inside them). This gives us the pair $a = b = 4$ (The pair $3$ and $4$ doesn't work in this instance due to the first restriction, detailed in the following paragraph). This outlines the one scenario in which $a$ can equal $b$: if there are two different ways to create a pattern with the same number of triangles.
Let me explain the restrictions. First restriction: none of the triangles can be the same in both constructions (and if the shape being constructed has some symmetry, the triangles can't be the same under that symmetry either). Hopefully the reason should be obvious; the following pattern outlines the loophole if this restriction didn't exist:

Second restriction: the constructions cannot be able to be non-trivially broken up into parts with different $a$-$b$ values that sum to make the $a$-$b$ values of the whole shape in the same way. I'm not really sure how to define this rigorously -- I would hugely appreciate the community's help with this -- but for now hopefully the intuitive definition should suffice. (Again, see Empy2's comment.)
Hopefully you can understand the gist of my question now. Specifically, I'm looking for a general proof for a given $a$ and $b$ that either there is some pattern that satisfies my question, or a proof that there isn't. Part of this question could involve finding infinite families of $a$-$b$ pairs. For example, the respective iterations of the Sierpinski triangle lend themselves to an infinite family; for example, looking at iteration $2$:

It can be formed with either $5, 6,7,8,$ or $9$ triangles; however, many of these have triangles in the same position as others, meaning they are incompatible as pairs. The only ones that are made of entirely different triangles are $5$ and $9$, and $6$ and $9$, but $6$ and $9$ does not work since both constructions can be broken up into three copies of the first iteration of Sierpinski's triangle, mentioned at the start of this post. In fact, for iteration $k$ of the Sierpinski triangle, we get the pair $(\frac{3^k + 1}{2}, 3^k).$
Regardless, this leaves many possibilities unexplored, and I'd be very curious to know how to explore them, and what we'd find. Any help is appreciated!
Here's a table of some of the patterns I know, right now:
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline a & b \\ \hline 2 & 3 \\ \hline 2 & 4 \\ \hline 2 & 5 \\ \hline 2 & 6 \\ \hline 3 & 4 \\ \hline 3 & 5 \\ \hline 4 & 4 \\ \hline 4 & 6 \\ \hline k & 2k - 1 \\ \hline 4 + 3k & 6 + 5k \\ \hline 3 + 2k & 4 + 3k \\ \hline \frac{3^k + 1}{2} & 3^k \end{array}
Addendum: I believe that in the pair $(2, b)$, we must have $3 \le b \le 6.$ The lower bound because I don't think there's a way to put two triangles such that two different triangles make the same pattern, and the upper bound because there's no way to place two triangles such that they create more than $6$ non-overlapping shapes. Am I correct about this range? Is there a mathematical way to determine it for other $a$? (This is not a separate question, this is just part of figuring out my main question.)
(As a bonus question: are there any pairs $(a,b)$ for which there exists at least two fundamentally different patterns that can be constructed with both $a$ and $b$ non-overlapping equilateral triangles?)

Do you want 'prime' patterns that can't be divided into smaller patterns.  For example two of your $(2,3)$ give $(4,6)$ or $(5,5)$

@Empy2 That's a good point. I would aim for "prime" patterns (although the non-prime question could also be studied), meaning that my $(6,9)$ pair does not work. I'll edit accordingly, thanks for pointing that out!

We can obtain $(2,5) $ with two triangles of different sizes, with the smaller one with a corner touching the side of the bigger one.

@caduk Kinda like the Star of David, but one triangle is too small to have all three vertices outside the other triangle. Cool, I'll put it in the list! (If I'm right about the possibilities for $2$, we now have all the possible $(2,b)$ pairs.)

A line intersects a triangle on at most two sides, so with two triangles, each side is cut at most twice, resulting in a total of 18 segments, so a maximum of $6$ triangles. Triangles can appear in only two orientations (opposite from each other): A segment can only be reused in a triangle with sides that are at a multiple of 60° from it. If segments are at an angle not multiple of 30°, then their respective classes of segments (that are at multiples of 60° from each other) will generate separate patterns. Two triangles with the same orientation can only intersect twice instead of 6 times.

Applying the same reasoning as with two triangles, we get a maximum of 37 segments, so 12 triangles. However, 12 is not possible, because there is only one drawing with 37 segments (36 is not possible), and it can't be broken in 12 triangles. $(3, 11)$ is possible, and by modifying it, probably all the $(3, b)$ for $4\leq b\leq 11$. $(3, 3)$ does not seem possible.

By the same logic as @caduk's 37 segments above, suppose the $a=2n$ triangles include $n$ upright and $n$ upside-down triangles.  The total edges is at most $3n+3n+12n^2+4{n\choose2}+4{n\choose2}=16n^2+2n=4a^2+a$, so $b\le(4a^2+a)/3$.  If $a=2n+1$ then $b\le(4a^2+a-2)/3$
